# weaving lists in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, merge, pattern-matching, currying

I'm trying to create a function to weave two lists together for example
`[1,3,5]` and `[2,4]` -> `[1,2,3,4,5]`

I get the basic principle of what I have to do and check for but I'm running into the problem that the required type

```
interleave :: ([a],[a]) -> [a]
```

is giving errors about different number of arguments. This is the version that's given me the least amount of errors so far

```
interleave ([],[]) = []
interleave (xs,[]) = [xs]
interleave ([],ys) = [ys]
interleave (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : interleave xs ys
```

I've tried messing with the arguments and outputs a few times but I'm new to haskell syntax so I don't really see where I'm going wrong

PART 2: Also I have a testing file to makes sure the functions are correct so if I'm still having trouble after this with that file (as I was getting similar input/output mismatches there which led me to change to what I have now) I'll probably post that code too for help

Comment: How are you using this function and what is the actual error you get?

Comment: @ReinHenrichs How am I using it? Just as it is I guess? Like make two lists and see if they weave together correctly, I'm not really using this in anything else but the tester file which is pretty much just take two lists and see if it weaves correctly. The error was "differing number of arguements"

Comment: A cute trick you might like: if you put the interesting case first, the last case can just concatenate the arguments. `interleave (x:xs) (y:ys) = x:y:interleave xs ys; interleaves xs ys = xs ++ ys`. It has a slight cost when `ys` is `[]` compared to your implementation, but it sure is pretty!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your type signature, and your three cases, are all defining a function of one parameter (of type `([a], [a])`), but then your fourth case is trying to define a function of two parameters (the first one being `x:xs`, the second `y:ys`).

The fix is to change the fourth case to also be over a single pair parameter:

```
interleave (x:xs, y:ys) = x : y : interleave (xs, ys)
```

Comment: @WalterC Alternatively you can modify all cases to take two parameters. Of course, this requires a slightly different type signature if you are giving it explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have a requirement to take only a single parameter, I think it would make more sense to change all cases to take two parameters:

```
interleave [] [] = []
interleave xs [] = xs
interleave [] ys = ys
interleave (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : interleave xs ys
```

Note that in the case `interleave xs []`, you originally returned `[xs]`. This is a list containing the list named `xs`. Instead you should return `xs` directly. Simlarly for the case involving `ys`.